# How to change the Sonar Dashboard URL from localhost:9000 to a specific IP in Email Notification Body Link

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I have enabled Email notification to few of my projects in SonarQube Dashboard, so that any issues assigned will be notified to the specific developer. The Link in Email body needs to be changed from "http://localhost:9000/issues/search#issues=AVtbuWsccyuRBiLrOmUr" to "http://IP:PORT/issues/search#issues=AVtbuWsccyuRBiLrOmUr". How do it achieve this.please help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In Sonar 7.6 this is under Administration > Configuration > General settings. Look for field "Server base URL".

Answer (score 1):

log as admin,
go to configuration -> parameters -> general

( or go to http://xxxxx/sonar/settings?category=general )

look the field -> "Server base URL"

fill this field and your email will be link correctly.

Comment: That's great!! thanks a lot, it worked. I have another query, some times my email notification works and some time it doesn't. Could you please tell me, what access you will need to send and receive email notification? Note: i have admin access to project level. im not a part of "sonar-administrators".